# How to show that the linear operator is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$. Define a linear operator $\mathit{T}$ on $\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
>
> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\mathit{T}\left(\mathbf{X}\right)=\mathbf{AX}\quad$ for $\mathbf{X}\in\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$
>
> Show that if $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonalizable, then $\mathit{T}$ is diagonalizable.

My intended approach is to show that there exists a diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ such that $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{P}^{-1}\left[\mathit{T}\right]_C\mathbf{P}$, where $C$ is the standard basis for $\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$, then I can conclude $\mathbf{D}=\left[T\right]_B$ for an ordered basis $B$ for $\mathcal{M}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$, and thus $\mathit{T}$ is diagonalizable.

Can anyone provide some advice on this?

Comment: are you familiar with eigenvalues???

Comment: matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then there is some matrix $P$ such that 
$$
P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix} a & 0\\0 &b \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Notice that 
$$
A\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
A\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
and so on for the other two standard basis vectors for $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: But how do I link that with T?

Comment: @Sapphire To diagonalize $T$ it is good enough to find a basis of $2\times 2$ matrices, say $M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4$, such that $T(M_i)=k_iM_i$ for $k_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over the field $F$.

Let $A$ be  a fixed $n\times n$ matrix over $F$.

let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ defined as  $T(B) = AB$.

Question is to check whether :

$A$ and $T$ have same eigen values??? (Linear algebra: Hoffman kunze 6.2.15)

let $\lambda \in F$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ i.e., $T(B)=\lambda B$ for some $B\neq 0$.

But, $T(B)=AB$ so, we have $AB=\lambda B$ i.e., $(A-\lambda I)B=0$

Now, $\det ((A-\lambda I).B)=0$ i.e., $\det (A-\lambda I).\det(B)=0$

Suppose $\det (A-\lambda I)\neq0$ this would imply $A-\lambda I$ is invertible and so $(A-\lambda I)B=0$ imply $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}(A-\lambda I)B=0$ i.e., $B=0$

So, $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ which imply that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Conversely, Suppose $\lambda \in F$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

I need to find some $B\neq 0$ such that $T(B)=\lambda B$

$T(B)=AB$ So, i have $AB=\lambda B$ i.e., $(A-\lambda I)B=0$

As $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible.

Now, Thanking an equivalent condition of [if $AB\neq 0$ for any non zero matrix $B$ then $A$ is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507772/if-ab-neq-0-for-any-non-zero-matrix-b-then-a-is-invertible) , we see that there does exist $B\neq 0$ such that $(A-\lambda I)B=0$ and thus we are done.

Thus, we see that $A$ and $T$ have same eigen values

Thus, $A$ is diagonalizable iff $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Why is it that if A and T have the same eigenvalues and if A is diagonalizable, then T is diagonalizable?

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable, it has $n$ distinct eigen values and each eigen value is also eigen value for $T$ So, $T$ has $n$ distinct eigen values and thus $T$ is diagonalizable and vice versa

Comment: But T needed n^2 linearly independent eigenvectors to be diagonalizable. So how can we be sure that the n distinct eigenvalues will give us n^2 eigenvectors?

Comment: I appreciate your question and i apologize for giving considerably wrong information.... I should say "matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots".. IS this alright now????

Comment: Hmm...minimal polynomial has not been covered yet. Is there any other alternative approach?

Comment: I have no other idea... Just give me some time.. i will try to edit...

Comment: Well, the hint given was to make use of the fact that a square matrix D is similar to [T]_C iff D=[T]_B, where C,B are ordered basis.

Comment: @ Praphaulla Koushik : If A is diagonalizable , then the minimal polynomial of A has no repeated roots, but how can you say that the minimal polynomial of T has no repeated roots. Can you relate the rank of A and T.

Answer (score 0):

If the field is not algebrically closed then the fact that $A$ is diagonalizable does not imply that T is diagonalizable.. suppose minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(x-c1)(x-c2)\dots(x-cn)$
and minimal polynomial of $T$ is $(x-c1)\dots(x-cn)(x^2+c)$ Then what?